# Run docker-compose without installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to run docker-compose without installation, so using `docker:compose` repository (with `docker run`).

So I tried this way :

```
docker run -ti --rm  -v $PWD:/XXX docker/compose:1.24.1 up -d
```

The problem is that I don't know the container dir name of `docker/compose` (here XXX) to mount my current folder as volume.

Any ideas...?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `XXX` folder can be anything inside the container. Basically in `-v` option of `docker run`. Its -v [host-directory]:[container-directory].

If you are trying to run a docker-compose up inside the container, then follow these steps:

- Create a directory on host `mkdir /root/test`
- Create `docker-compose.yaml` file with following contents:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  redis:
    image: redis
```

- Run `docker run` command to run docker-compose inside the container.

```
docker run -itd -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /root/test/:/var/tmp/ docker/compose:1.24.1  -f /var/tmp/docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

**NOTE:** Here /var/tmp directory inside the container will contain docker-compose.yaml file so I have used `-f` option to specify complete path of the yaml file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind mount your local `docker-compose.yaml` to any place just remember to tell `docker-compose` use `-f`, like next:

```
docker run -ti --rm  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ${PWD}:/code docker/compose:1.24.1 -f /code/docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

Meanwhile, don't forget to add `docker.sock` of your host machine bind mount to the container.